# Why Can't i see my containerized docker flask app in localhost:5000?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm trying to learn Docker containers. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to access the localhost of the container itself rather than my machine. Here is my docker container while_loop:1.5 running.

```
 Name-3:~ Name$ docker run while_loop:1.5
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

After running the `docker ps` command to get any running container info it displays the correct container running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
19795c23a73d        while_loop:1.5      "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   5000/tcp            distracted_shamir
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY ./app /home/programs/python/

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

RUN pip install flask

WORKDIR /home/programs/python/
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python /home/programs/python/main.py
```

After testing the simple flask app on my local machine, it works with no issues whatsoever. Not sure how to actually target the container.

`main.py` in case its needed:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which command you are using to run the container.  You probably need to provide the flag `-p 5000:5000` to the `docker run` command.

The `EXPOSE 5000` line in the Dockerfile doesn't actually cause that port to be opened:

[EXPOSE docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the `-p` flag on `docker run` to publish and map one or more ports

Given this, it's confusing that `docker ps` actually shows `5000/tcp`.  Once corrected you should see:

```
0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

where the former port is the exposed port, and the latter is the port in the container.